How to query RedisTimeSeries data on Grafana
I'm sure due to inexperience with Grafana I'm not typing the query correctly.
I have a RedisTimeSeries installed on my vm with data for a test key.

I am trying to create a chart/panel printing this data in a Grafana.  However, it doesn't appear to be getting this data as there is nothing appearing in my panel, and the query inspector seems to show 0 data being returned.


Testing my connection demonstrates that I did set it up correctly.  What am I doing wrong such that it's not getting the data?


So after experimenting some more, it looks like the time needs to be in epoch MILLISECONDS.  After I messed around with creating some datapoints in ms, then the chart showed lines.

